# Android hprov-dump giving me Error: expecting 1.0.3

Tags: android, hprof

I've used the Dump HPROF File option in eclipses DDMS and made my hprof file called in.hprof, but when I try to do the `hprov-conf in.hprof out.hprof` from the command line it gives me the error "Error: expecting 1.0.3". Any ideas?

Comment: So, any ideas to to solve "ERROR: expecting HPROF file format 1.0.3" without installing eclipse?

Comment: I [filed an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70147140) in the Android Studio bug tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never found out why it was giving me the error, but instead of trying to convert it and open it in the external MAT I ended up using the built in tool for Eclipse which worked perfectly and is much simpler. One click instead of exporting, converting and opening in a different window.

Comment: I'm not sure which built in tool is meant, but I used the eclipse memory analysis tool - http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: Please explain which "built in tool for Ecplise" you used and what for. Did you use MAT for (a) capturing the memory dump, (b) converting the Android Studio memory dump into the MAT-compatible format, (c) analyzing the memory dump which you managed to convert with some tool - which?