# ERROR: expecting HPROF file format 1.0.3

Tags: android-studio, heap-memory, hprof

I export heap dump as HPROF and I save it with the ***.hprof*** suffix according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html#save_the_heap_dump_as_hprof). When I run *hprof-conv* command, error occurs:

> ERROR: expecting HPROF file format 1.0.3

As a result I get **converted-heap.hprof** file with 0 size. And *Eclipse Memory Analyzer* can not open it.

Additional info:

- There is alike question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334620/android-hprov-dump-giving-me-error-expecting-1-0-3), but still converting error is not solved.
- If it matters, I use new *Android Studio 3* with it *Android Profiler* to export heap dump.

[image]

Comment: I [filed an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70147140) in the Android Studio bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

1.this hprof.file must click Dump Java Heap save file.(check you save .hprof file)
2.when you click Allocation Traking,save the hprof.file.will throw this error.